# How can I move facebook logout button to other navigation/view controller bundle?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

iOS app. Hamburger menu. So I need to move logout button from one view controller (fb feed) to other view controller (app settings)? How? Thanks.

Comment: Please add some details, what you have tried, and what is not working.

Comment: @bgse
This is only what I have related to login button

`if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)    
        {
            // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
        }
        else
        {
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            loginView.center = self.view.center
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

            loginView.delegate = self
        }
`

Answer (score 1):

If there is any `IBOutlet`/`IBAction` connected to the button, remove it. Delete the button from fb feed VC. Add a new button to App settings VC. Do appropriate customization of looks. Connect the `IBOutlet` if necessary. Paste the code of logout method in app setting VC. Connect this method to your new fb logout button. Do appropriate actions for replacing variables crucial for this method which were present in fb feed but not in app settings vc. Sorry for such  vague answer but you asked a vague question without providing any details.

Comment: The fact is that I haven't any logout button in storyboard